# What is making the menu active on scroll?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this template and have changed the content to suit what I need. I'm still in the early stages of learning jscript so wondered how the menu items were made 'active' as the page scrolls down? Basically I've taken the page apart and can see how the scrolling works but the menu won't change relative to the position on the page. Answers would be nice but as I'm keen to learn, an explanation would be even better.

Ta.

[CreativeTemplate](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to use your Developer tools (F12)

- Click F12 (Chrome Browser),
- Click on Sources
- Click on StartBootstrap-creative Folder
- Click on JS folder
- Find this script http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/js/creative.js

and after a quick look there you go:

```
// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});

// Fit Text Plugin for Main Header
$("h1").fitText(
    1.2, {
        minFontSize: '35px',
        maxFontSize: '65px'
    }
);

// Offset for Main Navigation
$('#mainNav').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 100
    }
})
```

you'll immediately see that it's a `.scrollspy()`, `.affix()` and other jQuery Bootstrap plugins in action.

Than eventually you use Goog and find this links like http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Many thanks Roko. As you say, think I need to concentrate on using the developer tools more :-)

Answer (score 0):

With that page, I actually could not access the dev tools, it is throwing an error.

So I did it the other way, right click>view page source.

It is in the "js/wow.min.js" script, however, i find the code is inefficient and i would do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop()> 200 )
{$('target-element').do something}); });
```

here a pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/RWodej